# Convert integer to big endian binary file in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, struct, endianness

I'm trying to convert a 2D-array composed by integers to a big endian binary file using Python by this way:

```
import struct;

fh=open('file.bin','wb')
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        fh.write(struct.pack('>i2',data[i,j]))

fh.close()
```

when I open it with numpy:

```
a=np.fromfile('file.bin',dtype='>i2')
```

The result is an array with zeros between original data:

```
[266,   0, 267,   0, 268,
   0, 272,   0, 268,   0, 264,   0, 266,   0, 264,   0, 263,   0,
 263,   0, 267,   0, 263,   0, 265,   0, 266,   0, 266,   0, 267,
   0, 267,   0, 266,   0, 265,   0, 270,   0, 270,   0, 270,   0,
 272,   0, 273,   0, 275,   0, 274,   0, 275]
```

That's what I'm trying to obtain:

```
[266,   267,  268,  272,  268,   264,  266,  264,  263, 
 263,   267,  263,  265,  266,   266,  267,
 267,   266,  265,  270,  270,   270,  272,  273,  275,  274,  275]
```

Do you know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `i2` with `I2` works for me.

```
a = np.fromfile('file.bin',dtype='>I2')
```

Then again, the `np.fromfile` behaviour seems weird (it says `>i2` is int16, but when you explicitly say `np.int16` it outputs something else).

```
In [63]: np.fromfile('npfile.bin',dtype='>i2')
Out[63]: array([  0, 345,   0, 245,   0, 345,   0, 245], dtype=int16)

In [64]: np.fromfile('npfile.bin',dtype=np.int32)
Out[64]: array([1493237760, -184549376, 1493237760, -184549376], dtype=int32)

In [65]: np.fromfile('npfile.bin',dtype=np.uint32)
Out[65]: array([1493237760, 4110417920, 1493237760, 4110417920], dtype=uint32)

In [66]: np.fromfile('npfile.bin',dtype=np.int16)
Out[66]: array([    0, 22785,     0, -2816,     0, 22785,     0, -2816], dtype=int16)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I need the output in big endian int16 (>i2). I work with np.fromfile only for read it.   Thanks

Comment: I haven't changed the endianness anywhere. `i` is int (4 bytes) and `I` is unsigned int (4 bytes).

Comment: Yes, but i think that the problem is in the struct module:  fh.write(struct.pack('>i2',data[i,j])) . It writes zeros between the input data and i don't want them.

Comment: Then write your values as `short` using `struct.pack('>h',data[i,j])`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an integer is 4-byte long. When you pack the integer using the struct.pack module, you force it into 2 byte chunks which splits the integer into two short-ints; one significant block with the actual value and the other significant block with the zero.

Thus when you read it via numpy, it loads the values with the trailing zeroes.

As to how to solve it, simply replace the format string from '>i2' to '>i' both while packing and loading from numpy. It should give you the expected results.

Comment: Well finally Kedar was Right, and using the >h stament worked. Thanks for you reply Pravesh