# numpy: writing large 2D arrays of uint16 in big endian

Tags: numpy

I am trying to save `512x512` `uint16 2D` arrays as binary frames of a binary movie. The format needs to be big endian, but I keep getting little endian data written (tried to read it in Matlab, java, it remains little-endian). I try to change the byte order as shown below, to no avail. I apologize is this a stupid question.

```
sys.byteorder = 'big'
for frame in range (0,1)
    fid.write(array)
fid.close()
sys.byteorder = 'little';
```

The following thread appears to be related, but if I try to change byte order with struct.pack I get junk written.

[Convert integer to big endian binary file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118838/convert-integer-to-big-endian-binary-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change force the byteorder of a numpy array using the `<`/`>` dtype specifiers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(5, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a.dtype.str
'<u2'
>>> b = a.astype('>u2')

>>> a.tostring()
b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00'
>>> b.tostring()
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04'
```